# Restricting the access based on time to a django view

Tags: python, django, timer, timezone

I am developing a django application for an exam which comprises two sections:

Section 1: Mcq

Section 2: Subjective

I am trying a scenario so that I can bind sections with time.

For example: Exam is of three hours. Mcq: 1 hour, Subjective: 2 hours

Now I want that exam should be active only for three hours. Mcq section should be active only only for first 1 hour and subjective section should be active for next two hours. Further, subjective section should be locked for first one hour.

I tried using timestamp. Basically I stored a time_start and time_end field in the models and locking the view using the difference between time_start and time_end. It works but I feel there should some efficient way of doing this. Further, in this implementation if users vary their system time they are able to manipulate the test timer.

Is there any efficient pythonic way or some django trick for such scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: I will ask a lame question, doesn't datetime.datetime.now() should get you server time?

Comment: Yes it will.I have used that for time_start and added the duration to time_start to make time_end. I am looking for something efficient like url expiration or blockage.

Comment: I haven't used celery, but you can give it a try, its a scheduler.